Calculated Column based on 2 columns, one a choice the other a number
I am trying to create a calculated column with multiple conditions.
So, the Application “Status” is “Over Due”, if the Stages column is still “Stage 1” and the “Days since Application” is 5 days or greater.
If the Stages field is “Stage 2 or more” it will be on “On Track”.
What is the formula to put in SharePoint lists to create “Application Status”?
The current formula below is not working
=IF([Days since Application]>5,IF(Stages="STAGE 1","OVERDUE","ON TRACK"))




Stages
Days since Application
Application Status




Stage 1
4
On Track


Stage 1
6
Overdue


Stage 2
7
On Track




Try using formula like below for your SharePoint list calculated column (Application Status):
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([Days since Application]), ISBLANK([Stages])), "", IF(AND([Days since Application] >= 5, [Stages] = "STAGE 1"), "Overdue", "On Track"))

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].

Output:


I would probably go with something like this:
=IF(AND([Days Since Application] >= 5,Stages="STAGE 1"),"OVERDUE","ON TRACK")


Thanks for your feedback....I eventually got this to work
